# The ability to "activate" some tags and search

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Tags are definitely making for search, but they are not utilized: one can only click on one tag, or depends on all the set of tags one selected: which generates too many results.

A tag group should be enabled to be used as a searching criteria.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use e.g. `[c] [mysql]` in the search field to find questions with those two tags.

That is, just add tag(s) in square brackets to the search field to filter found questions by that tag(s).

Comment: Thanks for the trick, chronos.  Still like a mouse enabled feature to make it easier.