# A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-hierarchy

**Executive summary**

Introduction of ***sparse* hierarchy** (partial inheritance relation) into the set of tags on Stack Exchange sites, in order to allow more efficient question organization/filtering/tagging (especially via "Interesting"/"Ignored" mechanism).

The proposal is designed to achieve its goals while adhering to two principles:

- As much backwards compatible as possible - e.g., all work-flows/GUIs not related to tags should remain 100% identical; and any work-flows related to tags should remain very similar (with exception of new tag creation for lower-rep users).
- As far as data population, this is intended to be a gradual incremental process - e.g. instead of one-time massive hierarchical classification, it is intended as an incremental addition/improvement of relationships.

**Why bother? (aka use cases)**

- As a use case #1, take a fictitious user "*Larry Ceiling*" . He is a Perl expert, and would like to ensure that every Perl question has good, complete and accurate answer. To do so, he will need to either use "Interesting Tags" mechanism, or to employ a search by tags.

  Currently, "*Larry Ceiling*" needs to use between **15 frequent** Perl-related tags to ensure "good enough" coverage and **at least 40 all perl-related tags** to ensure full Perl coverage.

  Searching for `"perl*"` isn't good enough (because many Perl-related tags do not contain the word "Perl" - for example [autovivification](/questions/tagged/autovivification) or [moose](/questions/tagged/moose) or [dancer](/questions/tagged/dancer)).

  In addition, due to new tag additions, this list needs to be maintained  by virtue of monitoring for new Perl-related tags.

  What Larry wishes is a way to simply say that he's interested in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tag, and achieve the correct result.
- A mirror use case is user named "*Jon Biathlon*", who would like to never see another C#, or .net question for whatever reason. I estimate the amount of C#/.net tags far exceeds Perl ones, and "Jon" will need to add every single one of them to "Ignored Tags" list or exclude from searches.
- More use cases are in the examples in **Benefits** section.

**Solution**

Add an ability for a **many-to-many** transitive relation "contained in" (aka "sub-tag") between **some** tags.

Just to be clear - the relationship will be **sparse**. NOT every tag will need to have a parent.

- This relation would **only** be applied to completely contained tags. For example, [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) tag would be contained in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag; but [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags would be completely independent. [garbage-collection](/questions/tagged/garbage-collection) would be independent of [java](/questions/tagged/java).
- The relation could be **many-to-many**, for example [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b) tag would be contained in both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and, if such exists, [visual-ms-languages](/questions/tagged/visual-ms-languages) tag. However, I don't envision too many cases where multiple ancestors would exist - see next bullet point for the reason.
- Some composite tags should be split up. For example, all of [perlre](/questions/tagged/perlre), [boost-regex](/questions/tagged/boost-regex) and [apache-regex](/questions/tagged/apache-regex) need to be changed to [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) + specialized tag (Perl, boost or apache correspondingly). This is the reason I believe multiple ancestors would be rare.
- Tag relationships can be specified by either a creation of a new tag, or via a special "relate tags" management screen.
- When tagging a question; the GUI allows "searching" for tags by sub-string via auto-complete drop-down (as we do now), **or** by browsing a tag hierarchy, e.g. typing "C++>" will bring up a drop-down of all children of `[C++]` tag.
- **NOTE** To increase backwards compatibility, we may want to only enable the "include descendant tags in searches" if the special form of the tag is used in Include/Exclude/Search (e.g. `[perl]` vs. `[perl*]`. Personally I don't think this is needed but may address the concerns by people that automated inclusion/exclusion of more questions may be disconcerting).

**Proposed permissions**

To shorten the post, I removed a detailed proposal for permissions required for creation of tags AND tag hierarchies - see edit history if you're genuinely interested. </Fermat>

**Implementation - technical**

Add 2 new tables (I don't know exact table structure of SE, so details may be off):

```
Table 1: *tag_contained* (parent-child relationship)
| parent_tag | tag | approved (could be >1 column) |
```

This table contains the relationship definitions. It is populated either when a new tag is created to be a child of an existing tag, or when a user with sufficiently high rep (say 250, or 3000 for "*TOP*" parent) proposes a new relationship, with "approved" value of false.

In addition it would contain newly proposed "top level" tags, with a special "*TOP*" parent tag value - but once approved, such records can probably be removed from the table.

When a user who can approve (10k? moderator?) approves it, "approved" is updated to true value.

This table is also used by the "tag population" GUI, by listing N-level drop-down menu instead of current 1-level auto-complete drop-down (better GUI approaches are welcome!)

```
Table 2: *tag_contained_expand*
| ancestor_tag | tag |
```

This table contains ALL transitively computed relationships. E.g. if the first table contains A->B, B->C, C->D, this table will contain A->B, A-C, A->D, B->C, B->D, C->D. This table is populated automatically based on all approved rows in the first table, either by a regular job or by a trigger. Since I do not anticipate an unduly high amount of tag relationships, this should not be overly intensive process.

The second table is actually used by search engine, include and ignore mechanisms - namely, a query of a type "where tag in (X,Y,Z)" will be expanded to join with *tag_contained_expand*.

It will also be used when tagging a question, by eliminating un-needed ancestor tags. E.g. a question with [perl5.10](/questions/tagged/perl5.10) tag would not need [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tag due to "contained in" relationship between them, and thus the latter will be either automatically removed or suggested to be removed (I suggest automated + notification).

- **NOTE** One additional technical detail - for Google's permission, the ancestor tags of question need to be included (hidden or visible?) on the question.

**Benefits**

- Main benefit is, of course, much simplified searching and filtering as illustrated in use cases.
- Some of the 35000 tags (especially composite ones) could be removed, as their only reason for existence is to denote hierarchy. Examples. [perlre](/questions/tagged/perlre), [boost-regex](/questions/tagged/boost-regex), [vc++-project-file](/questions/tagged/vc%2b%2b-project-file).
- Overly-specialized rarely used tags - [visual-studio-2008-sp1](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008-sp1) - which are the main candidates for being something's child - no longer pose a problem for either searches/filtering, OR for finding them when tagging a question.
- Misspelled and differently-spelled tags pose less of a problem as well. Much easier to find assorted `.net` and `dotnet` related tags if they are all under a single `[.net]` hierarchy. I realize that tag-synonyms may solve this particular problem, but it's still a problem meanwhile.
- A problem of finding tags that are related to some topic but have nothing at all common as far as wording is removed. [autovivification](/questions/tagged/autovivification) is a lot easier to find in a list of perl's children than on its own, especially for people who don't necessarily remember that word.

**Potential issues and resolutions**

- *Issue*: Tags that apply to multiple domains creating logistical nightmare. For example, C++/memory-allocations, Java/memory-allocation, etc...

  Solution: [memory-allocations](/questions/tagged/memory-allocations) should be independent of either of those 2. The examples above should be 2 independent tags each.
- Issue: It is very hard to organize 35000 tags into a tree, never mind do it correctly.

  Solution: The 3 components of "hard" assessment are sheer volume, the fact that most tags are really independent of each other, and the difficulty in placing certain tags under just one parent.

  First of all, a vast majority of the tags will not be in a single tree. There will be many top level tags and **the forest would for most part be rather flat** and sparse.

  Second, this is meant to be a gradual incremental process. 10 tags related first day. 5 tags second day. All Perl tags within 2 weeks (I'll volunteer :). etc...

  Third, while rare, multiple parents are allowed, thus eliminating "but it belongs to both!" headaches. Although, as noted, most cases when it appears that the tag belongs to multiple parents, either it should be independent in the first place, or it is a composite tag which should be split into two.
- Issue: This proposal is too bloody long

  Solution: I should get more sleep.

**Uniqueness**

NOTE: this question is NOT a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags), since it contains detailed proposal instead of a general idea. Some of the ideas are based on results of [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons).

Comment: Ok, read. I like it.

Comment: Sounds like a right hot mess of adding complexity in what should be simple and straightforward.

Comment: @random - *seamless* complexity. Unless you're creating new tags, the system behavior is 100% backwards compatible other than including more posts in a search. Even underlying technology change is fairly simple/low impact

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag hierarchy to browse through tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags)

Comment: @random it's really not simple and straight forward though.  we have issues on sites such as sff, movies, and literature because we as a community WANT people to be able to find stuff by particular authors or directors, but it's not always guaranteed to be tagged on the question.  if we had the option for a "meta" tag to group up particular tags, and have it community driven, that would add amazing usability to our sites

Answer (score 49):

Sorry, but this sounds like a nightmare to use.

You basically hand-wave most of the issue away by saying that `memory-management` should be a top-level tag.  Okay, great, let's use that as an example.

- Should `memory-management` be a subset of `memory`?
- Should `memory-leaks` be a subset of `memory-management` (keeping in mind that memory leaks are still possible in garbage-collected environments)?  Should it be a subset of `memory`?
- What about `memory-usage`?  `outofmemoryexception`?
- What about `memory-allocation`?
- What about `malloc`, which **is** specific to C/C++?  Does it go under `memory-allocation`, which is a general tag, or one of the C tags?

You say you don't predict many multiple-ancestor issues; I submit that the vast **majority** of tags fall under this umbrella.  Even seemingly-innocuous tags like `c#` could technically go under both `.net` and `mono`.  `apache` can go under `linux` and `windows`.

Not only is the maintenance a nightmare, but managing the search results are completely non-intuitive.  If I search for `wcf`, I don't need a bunch of questions tagged with `wcf-data-services` popping up.  Some 10k user might rightly decide that it's a subset of `wcf`, but I never use it so it has very little relevance to me (and `wcf-data-services` questions are, thankfully, rarely tagged with `wcf`).

It's going to be an endless source of confusion and arguments.

It never ends.

You know what's a **lot** simpler?  Tagging a perl question with `perl`.  We get 5 tags per question, it shouldn't be that hard.  If users can't be bothered to tag their questions correctly, then I don't think Larry should really be worrying about them.

Hyper-specialized tags like `visual-studio-settings` (2 questions!) should just be merged into their "parent" tags.

---

Fine, since "memory" is an abstract concept and you seem content to just fire off answers to those as though everybody in the world would agree, here's another, more targeted example.  Take the following tags:

`c#` `vb.net` `.net` `linq` `linq-to-sql` `entity-framework` `nhibernate` `linq-to-xml` `linq-to-objects` `linqdatasource` `linqpad`

Let's seriously start thinking about how to organize these.

Linq is definitely part of .NET.  It's technically part of C# and VB.NET as well, and is *different* for both of them.

Linq to SQL could be thought of as a subset of Linq.  But its scope goes far beyond Linq, it's an entire ORM framework.  If `linq-to-sql` goes under `linq`, so should `entity-framework`.  Does that make sense?

`linq-to-nhibernate` is *definitely* about `nhibernate`.  But it is also about `linq`.  If I search for questions on `nhibernate`, I probably *do* want to see questions on `linq-to-nhibernate`.  But if I search for general questions on `linq`, I almost certainly *don't* want to see the `linq-to-nhibernate` or `linq-to-sql` questions.

`linqdatasource` is technically a subset of `linq`, `linq-to-sql`, and `asp.net` (being a web server control).  But what is the actual likelihood that I want to see questions on `linqdatasource` if I search for either `linq` or `asp.net`?  Almost nil in both cases.

And what about `linq-to-xml` and `linq-to-objects`?  Surely you aren't going to tell me that `linq-to-xml` should go under `xml` or that `linq-to-objects` should go under objects.  Are you?  Well, it's hard to say; if I happen to be looking for questions about XML, Linq to XML is the de facto way of working with it in .NET now.  So I don't want to search for *all* questions about .NET, just questions about `.net` **and** `xml`, which is a fairly logical search parameter.  Except, if I'm not looking for .NET XML questions specifically, it makes *no sense whatsoever* to show me Linq to XML questions.

And `linqpad`.  Well, it's definitely `linq` related.  It's all *about* Linq.  But rest assured that I don't want to see questions about `linqpad` when I search for `linq`.  It **is** a genuine "containment" relationship, but nevertheless a completely useless one, I'm usually not interested in giving tech support on a program based around Linq to SQL/EF.

I repeat: There is no end to the pain and anguish that a tag hierarchy would cause.

I will take this conclusion one step further: **The *lack* of a hierarchy is the *raison d'être* of a tag system.**  Adding hierarchy semantics to a flat tagging system is *creating* the very problem that the tagging system was supposed to solve/circumvent; all in order to solve what is basically a non-problem (is it *really* that hard to find questions about Perl or .NET, and does it matter if your favorite/ignored tags occasionally pick up *one or two* false positives?)

Comment: @DVK: I disagree.  As I explained and you actually quote in your comment, memory leaks can happen in garbage-collected environments where you don't "manage" memory at all.  It makes no sense to search for `memory-management` and have `.net` questions coming up.

Comment: What about malloc, which is specific to C/C++? Does it go under memory-allocation, which is a general tag, or one of the C tags? - BOTH! Thanks for finding a great example of multiply contained tag for me!

Comment: @DVK: You keep answering these rhetorical/hypothetical questions as if they are simple truths, but they are in fact just **your opinion**.  Everything makes sense when there's only **one person** making the decisions.  In real life, different people have different opinions and there is considerably more ambiguity than you want to admit.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment that many tags have multiple parents. In your example, I'd say that apache is independent of both Linux and Windows, although it might theoretically qualifyt as being under web-development. Again, the priciple is to err on the side of NOT having a relationship unless one is 100% crystal clear.

Comment: @Aaronaught - you're wrong according to Wikipedia. "Garbage collection is the automated allocation, and deallocation of computer memory resources for a program. This is generally implemented at the programming language level and is in opposition to **manual memory management**". So garbage collection - aka automated memory management - is in fact a part of memory management, alongside with "manual memory management".

Comment: @Aaronaught - yes, I answered with my opinions (I removed most of my comments since they merely seem like nose after re-reading). If there's a difference of opinions, that's what rep limits and MSO discussions are for - but to repeat again, if there's a legitimate uncertainty, the logic is to err on the side of NOT relating the tags. My whole proposal is designed to deal more with multiple-branched obviously related tags (all flavors of visual-c++) as opposed to "ALL tags"

Comment: @Aaronaught - on the other hand, you are disagreeing with that LIMITED APPLICABILITY proposal by trying to dredge up examples of tags that either are, or appear to you, to be hard to hierarchise, and using that as a reason against having ANY tags hierarchycal

Comment: @DVK: Quoting Wikipedia doesn't make the scenario any less ridiculous.  A question about a memory leak in .NET is not a question about memory management.  It's a question about a memory leak.  I have no control over the memory management and don't really care about the implementation details of the garbage collector.

Comment: @DVK: Re: "That's what meta is for" - do we *really* want to spawn an entire class of new discussions/arguments based around a tag hierarchy, just so we can help Larry find the 3 questions that he missed with his umbrella `perl` search?

Comment: @Aaronaught - just because you are not using the correct term doesn't make anything ridiculous. If you're not interested in manual memory management tags (or wcf-data-services tags) that is what ignore list is for - you use a combination of includes and ignores.

Comment: Finally, @DVK, re: "limited applicability", see my updated example.  Those are all **very** popular tags, so hardly "limited."

Comment: @DVK: I am not using the correct term?  What are you on about?  Memory leaks are simply not a fully-contained subset of memory management, any Java/.NET/python developer can tell you that, and you're demonstrating a perfect example of how contentious this will become.  Why should I have to concoct absurd combinations of include/ignores just to get the same results I'm **already** able to get relatively easily with the existing tag system?

Comment: @Aaronaught - What does a tag popularity have to do with unambiguity of its hierarchy? Matter of fact I'd expect the vast majority of relationtips to involve LESS used/popular tags. E.g. nhibernate1.0 (I made that up) is OBVIOUSLY under nhibernate, whereas the rest of your example (which I'm not qualified to agree or disagree with) is clearly not obvious based on your (to-me-seemingly-expert-sounding) objections. Again, the whole idea is to only put in the stuff that is 100% clear and un-ambiguous as, for example, defined by a set of top answerers for a specific tag.

Comment: In other words, If I say `linq` should include `linq-to-nhibernate`, I don't count as I didn't exibit the necessary expertise (which I of course don't even have) on the topic. And the moderator who approves said relationship should pay attention to that. Whereas if I or better yet Sinan say that "mod-perl" shoud belong to perl tag, we are qualified, especially Sinan :)

Comment: @DVK: As I mentioned, frivolous tags like `nhibernate1.0` should just be merged into their logical "parents".  It's easy to do, and is one of the reasons (I assume) why lower-rep users are allowed to retag. As for the level of expertise required to make hierarchy decisions, (a) experts don't/shouldn't always agree, and (b) it seems antithetical to the Stack Overflow philosophy which is that content matters, not users.

Comment: @Aaronaught - regarding (b), you can not create a new tag with <250 rep. You can not re-tag with <500. You can not do MANY changes to content till you can be trusted by the community. For the same exact reason you should not be able to do a much more damaging act of creating a hierarchy (damaging because it CAN create confusion) unless you have shown you can be trusted.

Comment: @Aaronaught - regarding (a), again, you seem to be completely ignoring one of the most central points of the proposal. If there's ANY obvious ambiguity/disagreement among clear experts, leave things as they are and don't associate. Very simple.

Comment: @Aaronaught - how many of those frivolous tags did you personally merge in? And why do you feel that indicating a specific version via a tag is a Bad Thing, instead of a very valid way of allowing people a quick assessment of a problem domain? Those tags are a hassle/nuisance today specifically due to lack of hierarchy, but with it they become a very nice information conveyor.

Comment: @DVK: 500 rep is not hard to reach. I'm not ignoring anything you said, I'm pointing out that what you claim to be a minor issue ("oh, in that edge case, just leave it alone") is actually the common case. The truly unambiguous tags (such as version-specific tags) are edge cases that are easily handled by merges or simply adding multiple tags to the question. A feature request of this size and complexity is hardly justified if it would only be used for the long tail of tags (i.e. tags with fewer than 100 questions, many with less than 10).

Comment: @Aaronaught - 500 rep is not hard to reach but it still contradicts the notion that it's NOT about the users at all and only content - despite only affecting 1 question

Comment: @DVK, come on, you know what I meant, let's not split hairs.  The 250/500 limits are mainly compromises to prevent outright spam/abuse of the tag system.  Aside from that, tags are under control of the masses, the 12,000 or so users with retagging privileges, not a panel of experts.

Comment: It's been a long while since the question has been asked, but I'd like to point out something - just because you allow inheritance for tags, does not automatically enforce it on all users. Just make it optional. yeah, `linq-to-sql` goes under `linq`, but by searching `linq` you only get `linq`, and you can get all the children too by a special search. That answers both the cases where all children makes sense (i.e. `django-admin` question should appear when searching `django`) and the ones where you don't (i.e the `memory` example). I think both @DVK and @Aarobot are correct

Comment: As an example of what I see as a problem: there are over 15000 questions tagged winapi but *not* tagged windows.  So at least 18% of Windows questions are not properly tagged.  It may seem that tagging "shouldn't be that hard" but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That isn't a problem. There's no basis to assume that everybody with interest or expertise in Windows programming has equivalent interest or expertise in the Windows API. This is just another instance of failing to understand what the tag system is actually for. It's a way to express interest in a topic; if somebody is really interested in `winapi`, they can favourite that tag too.

Comment: @Aarobot: perhaps I'm overlooking something; how does favouriting a tag help me here?  Is there a page I can go to that shows new questions for all of my favourite tags?  (Leaving aside for a moment the issue of how to discover all of the Windows-related tags that may exist.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: *What*? That's the *whole point* of tags. Questions with your favourite tags automatically get highlighted, you can search by any tag (or multiple tags), every tag has an RSS feed, and so on and so forth. It's [right there in the help!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Honestly, questions like that highlight just how flawed all of these proposals are; they pay no attention whatsoever to usability or usefulness, they're just born out of an anal-retentive programmer-centric desire to *refactor*. Great for code, horrible for real life.

Comment: @Aarobot: none of the functionality you describe addresses in any obvious way my desire for a straightforward way to see all new Windows-related questions.  Personally, I think that would be useful.  Similarly, if I'm searching for an answer to a Windows problem it would seem useful to be able to find it without having to guess at what alternative tags people might have chosen.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You may think it would be useful, but the data says otherwise. 40 years of UX research has essentially proven that nobody likes or uses hierarchies; that's precisely the reason why modern sites use tags instead of the old-fashioned category hierarchies. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that there's something like a .001% chance that you could answer *any arbitrary question* that's even somewhat related to "Windows". Not even Raymond Chen knows *that* much. You don't have to guess at alternative tags, just look through the questions and favourite the ones you want.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that I should ignore the tagging system altogether and just look at every question.  That's absurd; there's too many of them.  And I know that being able to see all Windows questions would be useful *to at least some extent* because I've discovered questions that I could have answered at the time they were posted if I'd seen them - and the reason I didn't was that they were tagged winapi, or windows-7, or any of a dozen other tags, and I only see questions tagged windows.

Comment: I'm not wedded to hierarchies as a solution.  I'm just saying that there *is* a problem.

Comment: (I estimate closer to 0.3%, by the way; an estimated 150k questions, 446 answers.  Allowing for questions predating my arrival, perhaps as high as 1%.)

Comment: Aha!  The search `is:question intags:mine` does the trick, as far as finding new questions goes.

Comment: "Sorry, but this sounds like a nightmare to use.". As a developer you should able to accept challengers.

Answer (score 37):

Hierarchies are problematical. Heterarchies are less so.

What could work is a set of **clustering tags** -- eg:

**[perl/]** could mean **[perl]** and **[perlmonks]** and **[mess-up-like-perl]** and other tags.

**[status/]** could mean **[status-complete]**, **[status-norepro]**, **[status-declined]** etc

- A base tag can be in zero or more clustering tags.
- Members with over [5000?] rep points can edit/create the clusters.
- No question can be tagged with a clustering tag, only with base tags
  as now.
- No one **needs** to use clustering tags as all the base tags still work 
  the same.
- Those who want unusual clusters (eg
  **[1990s-technology]**) can argue amongst themselves until they have a
  clear definition of what base tags
  that may include.
- Later, more nuanced searches could be built by allowing ANDing (etc) of
  base tags and clustering tags, eg:
  [perl/] and not [golf]

Comment: Note that in searches, favorites and ignores, your `[perl/]` example is `[*perl*]` now and `[status/]` is `[status*]`.

Comment: I am not sure if you are assuming a specific precise definition of _heterarchy_: the definition in Wikipedia and Wiktionary says it means either _without ranking_ or _with multiple potential rankings_, which seems vague to me. I would find this system helpful but second best to a multi-parent hierarchy, as suggested in [Dukeling’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51435/290049).

Answer (score 19):

You definitely need a multi-parent hierarchy.

The what-should-be-a-child-of-what discussion is not really one for here. The bottom line is that it is possible to come up with a hierarchy. Given that this is a user-managed environment, the hierarchy should eventually stabilize at the most intuitive structure. If it's not clear where a tag belongs, just keep it on the top level; we're after **a** hierarchy, not the perfect one.

The hierarchy already exists, we just want to formalize it. Consider that some people will just tag something with `sql-server-2008`, while others will tag it `sql-server` and `sql` as well. A lot of discussion can go into which one is better, but the proposed hierarchy would cause the two to be combined.

There are consistently new tags popping up, and people need to favourite and ignore appropriately, having a proper hierarchy would reduce the need to do this.

Search engines consideration - It may be disadvantageous to tag something only with a tag at the lowest level, possibly losing a keyword indicating the language used which would decrease the rank of the results. Worth a thought.

Some thoughts on dealing with the problem of people getting results for things they don't want to get results for:

- You can have strong-inheritance (`sql-server-2008` child of `sql-server`) and weak-inheritance (`linq-to-sql` child of `linq`). strong-inheritance automatically includes the child, weak-inheritance optionally includes the child. This default allows your new users to hit the ground running without knowing about inheritance, and they'll figure out that when they search for `sql-server`, `sql-server-2008` also pops up. The inheritance structure explaining why a specific tag was included should probably also be displayed somewhere, with a link to an inheritance FAQ.
- Degree of inheritance. An extension of the above, allowing more than 2 choices when specifying how strong the inheritance is. This would probably allow for a better hierarchy, but this is a lot more complicated for everyone.
- You can specify whether you want to include children (strong/weak inheritance or both) when specifying a tag (as a favourite, ignored or in search), possibly using some affix.
- Ignoring `linq` and favouriting `sql` (both with weak inheritance) probably should cause `linq-to-sql` to be ignored, similar to the way it's working now with multi-tagging.
- Posting questions under certain tags (or tags high in the inheritance tree) should be demotivated (possibly with a warning when trying to use it) or disallowed. `sql` comes to mind, how many questions are there that fits under `sql` that wouldn't be better suited to be tagged under one of it's children? (I'm not saying there aren't any, just that there are few)
- Tagging something with a tag and it's parent should probably be disallowed (at least in the case of strong-inheritance, demotivated in the case of weak-inheritance).

Comment: As to the search engine consideration, a solution would be for the site to automatically present the parent tags.

Answer (score 10):

I totally support hierarchie**s** in the underlying implementation.

I see very little need for hierarchies in the basic user interface itself (except for moderators and people explicitly using the tag hierarchy).

In the SQL space, right now this is increasingly obvious.  If I want to see all SQL questions, this should include t-sql and pl/sql dialects etc.  If I want to see all sql-server questions, this should include sql-server-2000, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008.  This is especially important because of the 5 tag limit.  You cannot expect people to tag correctly at the moment since there is still no way to stop people repeatedly using the incorrect tags.

What we did for our technical support knowledge base was allow things to be tagged, but that tags could be multi-parented.  So if people were looking at a problem related to an HP 970 printer driver and margins, it would show up under printing, drivers, hp, hp-970, margins, etc.  And they didn't have to worry about the fact that there were multiple mount points for a tag or anything like that.  They didn't have to tag all the way up and the search would automatically find everything under whatever rollups because we cached the full traversal.

For improved performance, we cached the tree traversal up so that the data entry and management was normalized but the denormalized cached data could be used to ensure performance.

Comment: A freeform, multiple-parent hierarchy does address a number of the issues.  If it's practical to implement and maintain (not a trivial task in either respect) then this could work in tandem with or maybe even as a replacement of tag synonyms.

Comment: I think any user should be able to find the hierarchy, but it should not be too obtrusive. In particular, when tagging, one need not see much of it — though actually it would be really nice if the sub-tags appeared when one tentatively entered a tag!.

Answer (score 7):

I think many-to-many hierarchies are too complicated to manage, and very complex tree-like hierarchies also may be problematic, but there are some cases where hierarchy is the only logical way.

As example, I had issues with **LocalStorage** and **cache-manifest**, both of them being part of HTML5 specification. I've tagged my post also **html5**, since this tag is more popular and tagging it so increases the chance of being answered, and also **javascript**, since problem is with AJAX application. There are even more tags that could be appropriate, such as **offline**, **offline-cache**.

Of course unnecessary tags are one case (offline-cache is, I think, often mistaken with cache-manifest). But another case is this HTML5, which contains of mechanisms such as Local Storage and cache-manifest, so it is logical that these both should be subtags of the tag **html5**.

The same, I think, should apply to the various **jquery** extensions, which have separate tags, but practically whoever asks such question will also use basic **jquery** tag.

So in my opinion it should be **at least** simple one-level hierarchy. Two levels would be even better, but the greater the hierarchy, the more important to manage this tags correctly. **Very high** reputation should be required to edit tag hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Far too much complexity for the problems you propose to solve.

I went cross-eyed trying to read the whole post, but I was simply not convinced by the "problems" you posit with the current system: those may call for a better means of telling the system what we are and are not interested in. They don't call for a complete rewrite of the post sorting mechanism.

Remember that we're going to have to explain all this to the users who

- want to search
- want to set their *interested* and *ignored* subjects
- obtain the ability to create tags

and that if they don't get it they're going to be here on meta asking about it. Over and over again.

There may be issues surrounding tag approval. Stack Overflow currently has more than 500 10k+ users. Can any one approve a new tag? What if other high rep users disagree? Are we going to end up with a voting system?

Comment: @dmckee - Users who want to search will not have anything changed (I just realized though that my proposal needs to be improved for Google's sake to include hidden ancestor tags). The only tangible change is that searching for, say "perl" , will return exactly the bigger set of results that a random user would intuitively expect.

Comment: @dmckee - For people who want to set their interested/ignored subjects, again, the only difference is that more Qs will be returned/rejected - and heck, we can always make the "include ancestors" an optional behavior if there's a tangible confusion fact for that (e.g. the only search for ancestors is for "perl*" tag and not "perl").

Comment: @dmckee - however, they now get a small warning saying "you have perl and 16 other un-needed tags - you can just be interested in perl alone!)

Comment: I agree that people who want to create tags would undergo steeper learning curve - but seriously, being asked "this is a new tag you're creating, please choose its parent" seems like a very small learning curve, no?

Comment: Please note that there's no change in TAG creation - new tags do not need to be approved. Only the relationships of new tags need to be approved - again, the goal is to be as backwards compatible as possible.

Comment: And as I noted in an update, a good automated compromise system for relationship update may be: this requires *unanimous* approval of 3 10k+ users who are in top N answering ranks for one of tags in question. Any disagreements are resolved the way tag merges are today - MSO or moderator decisions.

Comment: But I'm perfectly comfortable with "if one high expertize user disagrees, err on the side of "no relationship", till that dissenting vote can be persuaded to join the yays (or never)

Comment: I can try to do some mock-ups since my explanations don't seem to convey just how small the changes will for the users

Comment: Good concerns overall, +1... hope I addressed some of them. I updated the proposal as well from ideas your concernes raised (perl vs. perl*; and google-centric listing of ancestor tags explicitly)

Comment: @DVK [The “perl vs. perl*” bugbear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190030) makes it effectively useless. Very annoying.

Answer (score -1):

> Searching for "perl*" isn't good enough (because many Perl-related
>   tags do not contain the word "Perl" - for example [autovivification](/questions/tagged/autovivification) or
>   [moose](/questions/tagged/moose) or [dancer](/questions/tagged/dancer)).

Could this be solved by an effort to add tag synonyms for the above, such as perl-moose and perl-dancer? It looks like tag synonyms are supported by wildcard searches for the most part.

Comment: That seems to require an awful lot of not so obvious effort all over the place. Do we really want synonyms for `lord-of the-rings` and `gollum` including `tolkien`, and one for `gollum` including `lord-of the-rings`?