# Using Parent Tag Then Child/Children Tag/s?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)

I was wondering out of the curiosity of promoting question tagging if it makes sense to you guys (those who ask, and maybe those who edit questions to modify the tags) for an example like this to be exercised:

```
Question: Something MSSQL 2005 related?
Tags:  sql (or) sql-server (We should primarily tag it as either or both(?))
       sql-server-2005 (A `child` type of tag of the `parent` type 
                        of tag "sql" or "sql-server")
       Final Tag list: sql sql-server sql-server-2005
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Just as a note, because such stuff arouses me: `[sql]` is not the same as `[sql-server]`. [SQL is the `Structured Query Language`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), the other is a Microsoft Database Server...

Comment: Thanks for that.. I was just wondering how related they (sql and sql-server tags) could be used in conjunction with tagging for most posts and the difference makes a difference indeed

Comment: Should we then differentiate [[tag:sql]] and [[tag:sql-query]] to make it more prominent from [[tag:sql-server]]? Over on [dba.se] we've just sidestepped it all by assuming that if code is present, it's probably just [[tag:sql]] to begin with

Comment: @jcolebrand: I'm all for branding that `[microsoft-sql-server]`, but I think that discussion was already lead...did I ever mention that I hate them for using generic words for their products? On the other hand, it was one hell of an awesome marketing move...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are familiar with tag synonyms right?

This sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: Tag synonyms appear (to me.. so please tell me if I'm wrong) to be a direct one-to-one relationship, right?

Comment: so are parent-child, from the perspective of the child.

Comment: Sorry.. what I meant was that (now following the perspective you mentioned) a parent may have more than one child, and if tags aren't placed specifically to cover the affected range of a question, then to get to the child we should always have to include the parent, even though the child would have its own identity?

Comment: ohhhhh, I think I see what you're saying. You mean we should have all the pertinent tags? So [sql-server] and [sql-server-2005]?

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda the direction I wanna take this discussion to.. Also, imagine: Guy A would not be affected by just an `sql`-only tagged post if he's a guru, while Guy B who wants to just focus on sql 2005 would have to sift further in `sql` for `sql-server-2005` --this affects those who ask as well as those who answer.. Or am I being confusing again?

Comment: we limit tags as-is to a limit of five tags per Q. Your proposal would require an open ended number of tags.