# How about categorizing all the questions for easier look up?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)

There are millions of questions out there, and most of the questions to be asked have already been asked. I frequently see closed questions because of being "exact duplicate" of another question.

We may create a categorization tree along with (or instead of) the current tagging system. The tree will be something like this:

```
StackOverflow
|---- C++
      |---- Functions
      |---- Classes
      |---- Arrays
      |---- STL
            |---- Containers
            |---- Strings
            |---- ...
             .
             .
             .
      |---- ...
|---- Java
|---- Pascal
        .
        .
        .
|---- Algorithms
|---- Optimization
|---- Discussions
        .
        .
        .
```

Each question must belong to **at least** one category. Anyone looking for information will be able to browser this tree to the deepest branch and see the list of questions belong to that branch.

We can encourage users to categorize the huge pile of concurrent questions by offering them 1 point for categorizing 1 question. The tree will be empty in the beginning, but it will swell up as the uncategorized question become categorized.

We can make user choose one or more categories before asking their question. They won't see the edit box for question body and title until they chooses at least one category. By doing this, the automatically generated list of "similar questions" will display more accurate results (from the chosen categories).

What do you think about this idea?

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially nested tags, and that has been proposed before and declined (although I don't remember why, and can't find the relevant discussion right now).

Comment: Btw, Java also has functions, classes, and arrays. How should they be categorized?

Comment: **WHY**? What does this bring to the site that tags don't?

Answer (score 9):

That's what tags are for.

A hierarchical ontology like you're suggested is another way to organize data, but it has issues of its own. The tag system offers up quite a bit more functionality (in my opinion) and I expect the founders felt the same way. What you're suggesting is a complete re-imagining of Stack Exchange. Huge risk for little gain.