# Searching for perl* tags accidentally includes regex

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, wildcards

When you use a [wildcard tag search on questions with any perl* tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl*), it erroneously includes the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag in the search set:

[image: perl* tag search images]

Notice the `regex` tag at the bottom. It should not be there, because contrary to popular belief, `perl != regex`. :)

Comment: [tag:perl-regex] is a synonym of [tag:regex].

Comment: @TimStone That’s um, nuts.

Comment: @tchrist you are thinking about synonyms backwards.  They're one-way relationships, not two-way.

Comment: @Joe That may well be, but this is an unfortunate situation that makes such searches a big pain in the butt.

Comment: Is there no way to say "not ..." in search?

Comment: @Joe `-[regex]`

Comment: @Doorknob The problem is that that doesn’t work in the “favorite tags” selection. If I’ve selected `perl*`, I shouldn’t therefore get `regex` too.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work with the wildcard; still get regex-not-regular-perl in the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tag - [perl-regex](/questions/tagged/perl-regex) which is a synonym of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), as can be seen on its [synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/synonyms)

`perl*` will catch `perl-regex` which shows up as `regex` due to the synonym relationship.

Comment: How can this be a good thing? I’m pretty sure there are non-Perl regexes in existence.

Comment: @tchrist - Did I say it was a good thing? Synonyms are suggested and accepted by the community.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Somebody made a mistake then.

Comment: No, it's not a mistake.  The point of the synonym for [tag:perl-regex] mapping to [tag:regex] is that anything tagged [tag:perl-regex] gets moved to [tag:regex], which is fine.  [tag:regex] is not assumed to be related to perl in any way.  It just happens to come up with the wildcard search; perhaps that should be fixed, but I'm not sure it should be - in other similar cases you might prefer the synonym to be included.