# Where can I ask for an explanation of a paragraph about English grammar rules so that I can translate it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need help with translating a book into my native language. The paragraph I'm translating now is about some "artificial" grammatical rules in the English language and I need help to understand those.

Comment: Hi Abbas! you may want to check [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) we can help explaining English texts in basic English, as long as you

1. limit your question so that it is about a few words or a single phrase (but it's good to have the entire paragraph in question, for context)
2. [provide enough details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/18673) including your own thoughts on the matter; that way we can provide an answer that suits your needs, rather than a generic one which may be too complex or too simple.

Specifically, because it's a paragraph about English grammar, [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) may work too, but the same requirements apply.

Finally, if there's a Stack Exchange dedicated to your native language ([here is an unofficial list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331783/295232)), you might get some help there. Again, the same advice applies.