# Hierarchical Tags

Tags: feature-request

Take example of following tags:

wcf
wcf-binding
wshttpbinding

In this case wshttpbinding is a wcf-binding which is part of wcf.

Most probably the question is tagged with one or two of these. It would be nice to get the question whichever of these tags you searched on.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/meta-tags
(and others). As cletus notes, it's been repeatedly declined. As for why... There's a surprising amount of cross-pollination once you get beyond short branches and simple hierarchies. Imagine what would happen to your example if some library *other* than wcf used the term wshttpbinding!

Comment: I have the same issue. I have a `python` filter on my questions and routinely miss out on questions tagged `python2.7` etc and not `python`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff has stated there will never be hierarchical tags. From [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags):

> we will not be doing trees, in any
>   way, shape or form – Jeff Atwood♦ Jul
>   6 at 15:30

Although I see your point (and somewhat agree), tagging isn't meant to be perfect. It's meant as a guide.

Comment: Jeff Atwood [no longer work at Stack Exchange, Inc.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange/) - can we have hierarchical tags?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW...

If the tags are being well-used in the original question then I would expect (or at least hope) that the most restrictive tag should match what I am looking for.

If searching in a subject area for questions to answer I tend to search for the widest tag and then add relevant search terms to order the results usefully (e.g.  wshttpbinding [wcf] wcf-binding ) as the default OR on the search terms  wshttpbinding and wcf-binding with the tag wct should get the most relevant to the top of the list whilst excluding questions where the terms may be mentioned in answers but are not tag-worthy in the question.