# Do we need tag dependencies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags)
>   [Hierarchical Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/hierarchical-tags)

As we all know, any question on Meta should be tagged at least with one of following: bug, feature-request, discussion, support.

Nevertheless, I believe, there are some tags, usage of which automatically implies belonging to one of these categories.

For example, retag-request is feature-request as well.

So my question is - may be, I'm saying only may be, we should think about something like 
tag dependency - when using tag A automatically means that this question belong to category B?

**UPD:**  Just want to note that I'm not asking about tag hierarchy on any stackexchange site, I'm talking about meta. As for rules, by which we conclude that this tag is depended to that on, I'm proposing very simple rule. If, say, tag have postfix -kind, then tag kind is parent tag.

Comment: Overkill, in my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I guess, most possibly you are right.

Comment: Or this one, even better: [Could we make tags imply other tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that would be possible if all tags had a clear and unambiguous meaning. But as it is now, many haven't. So I can imagine I would want to use tag A, but in a different sense than category B. Thinking of it, I only see draw-backs.

- Many dependencies would be disputable. Would [concurrency](/questions/tagged/concurrency) belong to [database](/questions/tagged/database)? Concurrency can apply to many multi-user systems.
- Many tags could belong more than one category. [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate) could belong to [orm](/questions/tagged/orm) and [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source). Would I have to choose a category when I tag NHibernate? Better not.
- It would promote tag duplicates if people find a tag, but not in the right category.
- It would be a hell of a job to detect and maintain dependencies.

So, yes. Overkill.

**Edit:**

After your comment and edit: I think at meta pretty much the same would apply. The conventions that you mention would be clear enough.

Comment: Your answer is full an excellent. Just want to note that I've asked specifically about tags on meta, where we have a set of obligatory tags. Here, on meta, we can, for example, say that all tags with -request postfix are automatically requests.