# Getting more specific categories within a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible to provided tag intersections. Suppose I am looking at 'C++' tag and would like to look at file reading/writing specific questions within C++. If you could provide a left side pane which show tags that are intersecting with C++, I could easily find my desired set of questions, ie those which have been tagged as both 'C++' and 'files'

Comment: See this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/we-need-meta-tags-to-be-able-to-organize-and-search-tags-easily

Answer (score 4):

This already happens. Go to the [C++ tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) page. To the right are "related tags" that you can click through.

Comment: The related tags only show those that are on the set of questions that happened to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you can search for questions with multiple tags that you specify by using the magic urls: [/tags/bug+status-bydesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug+status-bydesign) will show you all the bugs that are not actually bugs.

I was just thinking about a similar issue. I do believe there should be some sort of 'tag associations'. That way, you would not have to tag a question has both <kbd>windows</kbd> and <kbd>windows-7</kbd>. Searching for 'windows' could show questions tagged with all Windows operating systems. Similarly, <kbd>office-2007</kbd> could show all <kbd>powerpoint</kbd> questions.

But then again, the reason the tags system is so good is because of it's simplicity. If not done carefully and properly, it could screw the whole system up by making to too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what the related tags are on the right panel? Clicking on them gives you the intersecting set of questions. The only drawback there is: it does not work with wildcard tags.

**Edit:** Lance commented that the related tags just are the tags that happen to be on the displayed questions on the page. I just made the test. Searching for [math] results in 920 questions. It displays [javascript] as a related tag with 16 intersecting questions. There is no question on the first page of results with the tag [javascript]. On later pages, there are 16 such questions featuring both tags. **Thus it seems that all intersecting tags in the whole result set are listed as related, thus being what the OP is looking for.** If I am wrong, please let me know.

These restrictions still remain:

If you click on your interesting tags list something like [delphi*] and then click on one of the related tags, instead of an *and* with the rest it will *or* the tag. Sometimes if the list of tags fitting the wildcard is long, this will result in an error.

Try the example I gave using [delphi*] (or delphi~ in search box) and click on winapi afterwards. This is the result:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+or+delphi-2009+or+delphi-7+or+delphi-2007+or+delphi-2006+or+delphi-5+or+delphi-prism+or+delphi-units+or+delphi-2010+or+delphi.net+or+delphi2007+or+delphi-php+or+delphi-components+or+delphi-library+or+delphi-like+or+delphi-1+or+delphi-3+or+delphi2009+or+winapi

See the or before winapi? Try to click the link, too.

It does work when searching using [delphi~] [winapi], resulting in the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi+delphi~

But then on the second page you will see that it resolves this to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=winapi%20delphi%20or%20delphi-2009%20or%20delphi-7%20or%20delphi-2007%20or%20delphi-2006%20or%20delphi-5%20or%20delphi-prism%20or%20delphi-units%20or%20delphi-2010%20or%20delphi.net%20or%20delphi2007%20or%20delphi-php%20or%20delphi-components%20or%20delphi-library%20or%20delphi-like%20or%20delphi-1%20or%20delphi-3%20or%20delphi2009%20or&page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=15

This is a different combination of and's and or's than expected.

Comment: see comment on Eric's answer on the related tags.