# Should the SQL Developer tag be named sqldeveloper, or sql-developer?

Tags: discussion, tags

For Oracle SQL Developer, which you run by typing `sqldeveloper`, should the tag be named [sqldeveloper](/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) or [sql-developer](/questions/tagged/sql-developer)?

I noticed there were exactly six of one and half a dozen of the other when I searched.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg

Comment: Voting to close because this has been resolved for some time ([sql-developer] won).

Comment: See also [Should tags take the form foobar or foo-bar?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2813)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sql-developer - separate the words!