# Community user performing automatic tag tuning

Tags: discussion, community-user

I found the following on an old [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19172/166025):

> Do not re-tag only to change the format of the tag (ie: stackoverflow
>   -> stack-overflow). This is done automatically by the community user.

Is the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user programmed to retag posts? I am asking because I haven't seen any such retagging done by the Community user, and I haven't found any recent reference to this activity in the FAQ, or any other post.

Should we avoid retagging posts to change the format of tags such as adding 'dash' for multiword tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the community user is indeed doing tag tuning and it appears on [its profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all&page=5712), saying "Automated tag tuning" in the edit remark.

From what I was able to find it's doing those actions:

1. [Changing the tags order](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/361/revisions). (See revision #4.)
2. [Changing tag name by making it plural (adding "s")](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29890/revisions).
3. [Adding tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47522/revisions).

I'm pretty sure this is part of automated process, couldn't find any official source though.

As for the question at stake here, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148950/152859) covers it nicely.

Comment: Thanks for finding that but all of these edits are from 2008. I guess Stack Overflow team must have disabled auto tag tuning later on. I see some problems in auto tag tuning by the Community User, for example in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22135/309086), [tag:http] tag was replaced by [tag:https] tag assuming a singular to plural change but it is wrong and was corrected back by another user.

Comment: There is good chance there were such edits later on, but I can't really search in over 1000 pages of revisions. :(

Comment: Isn't tag order solely dependent on tag popularity?

Comment: @Asad now it is done automatically when adding or editing a question but it wasn't like this always.

Answer (score 2):

> Should we avoid retagging posts to change the format of tags such as adding 'dash' for multiword tags?

You cannot create a tag that is similar to the another one, and the difference is the presence or absence of hyphens. If you do it, you get a message saying, "You are attempting to create the tag [new tag]; however the tag [old tag] already exists!"

[image: screenshot]

The only users who can create those similar tags are moderators, who can rename tags without retagging every single question.

As for the Community user retagging questions, I have never seen this happening.

Comment: Maybe this check was added recently. I made a few edits for retagging [tag:sharepointdesigner] to [tag:sharepoint-designer]. Some examples: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1170218/revisions), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1277657/revisions), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1378997/revisions).

Comment: Found the reference to this check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107002/166025. This is for the future but question remains valid about the past tags.

Comment: If you find old tags for which the difference is just one or more hyphens, then you should ask to merge them. The meaning of [tag:multicore] is probably the same of [tag:multi-core], if there isn't a development product that is called Multi Core.