# Retagging convention in general

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tags: foobar versus foo-bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/tags-foobar-versus-foo-bar)

I was looking at a question tagged [windows2008] and thought it would be more appropriately tagged [windows-server-2008]. A quick check showed that [windows2008] had less than 10 questions associated whereas [windows-server-2008] had several hundred.

Is it safe to assume that where two tags are obviously referring to the same concept the tag with the highest number of associated questions (by a significant margin) is the most appropriate?

Also, is it helpful for me to retag in these cases or am I fixing a non-problem?

Comment: Here on meta, non-problems get fixed all the time :)

Comment: You could just do it yourself, that's the whole idea of this community-run stuff.. :P Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten involved in retagging or merging myself (maybe in the future), but I would post a question on here so it can be discussed by the community under any of the following conditions:

- There is *any* doubt as to the difference in meaning/subject between tags
- There are a lot of questions in the tag proposed to be removed, relative to the other tag(s) involved
- The tag proposed to be removed has more than a handful of questions

It's probably best to err on the side of caution, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I would edit this question, if I had enough rep, but consider:

```
[windows-server-2008]: 329 questions
[windows-2008]:         25 questions
[windows2008]:           3 questions
```

Also, please add the "retag-request" tag to this question. :)

**EDIT:** You can fit the `tag lengths as x` and the `number of questions as y` to the following equation: `y = 2.67*x*x + 39.6*x + 114.57`

Just in case you are wondering.