# Synonymize [terminal-services] ← [terminalservices]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135993) on the [clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) question, it appears that both [terminal-services](/questions/tagged/terminal-services) and [terminalservices](/questions/tagged/terminalservices) exist. I propose the following synonymization:

- [terminal-services](/questions/tagged/terminal-services) ← [terminalservices](/questions/tagged/terminalservices)

I propose the hyphenated version over the unhyphenated version as the merge target [as blessed by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-tags-take-the-form-foobar-or-foo-bar).

Comment: And there's quite a lot of other tags in that list too. You're not going to create a new Meta question for each one, are you?

Comment: @animuson: I thought that pair was particularly blatant (although I guess they all are), and [in the comments on that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags#comment466339_135993) it said to create a Meta question, so I did. But if that's not the best way to have two tags with many questions in each synonymized, please let me know what way you think would be preferable.

Comment: None of the tags in the hyphenated list need to be synonymized. Only retagged. If one of them is too hard to do by yourself, just skip over it. I go through those lists and plow through a bunch every once in a while when I get bored. It'll get done.

Comment: @animuson: Would it be worthwhile to start a new Meta question for two tags in that list if both should be a synonym of a third extant tag not mentioned in that list?