# How much work goes into a retag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Inspired by requests such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14276/retag-winforms-windows-forms).

I've been wondering how much work it takes the mods to perform a retag. Not that I want to ask for one, but simply because I'm curious ...

Also, as a side question which might be more interesting: Would there be some value to a system which automatically retagged certain popular retag requests behind the scenes? In other words, if a user asked a question and tagged it with "winforms," the StackExchange engine might automatically retag it "windows-forms?" (The only way I can see this working is if all retags performed by mods were tracked, and then as a retag was performed, StackExchange would learn that in the future no new questions should be allowed to use the replaced tag. Don't know what that would do to performance.)

Comment: a couple magical SQL statements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it takes to do a mass retagging is to put in the current tag and the tag we want, and the retag happens pretty much in an instant.

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!

Answer (score 1):

The way that moderators retag is through [batch retagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/batch-retagging).

Auto retagging has been discussed before.

[Tagging Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/do-23-000-tags-need-tag-database-editors/1406#1406)

[Automated Similar tags finder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/do-23-000-tags-need-tag-database-editors/652#652)

[Duplicate tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/do-23-000-tags-need-tag-database-editors/1529#1529)