# tag aliases/synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)

re: several tagging reorganizations...

If there is a canonical form of a tag (e.g. [the Java tags question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11786/merge-all-java-ee-related-tags-j2ee-jee-javaee-java-ee-into-one)) then it seems like the following set of features would be a good improvement:

example case (for illustration, not correctness):

**`j2ee`** is a canonical tag with aliases `javaee` `java-ee`

- if someone searches using tags that include an alias (`javaee` or `java-ee`) it gets mapped to the canonical form (`j2ee`) for a search.
- if someone edits the Tags section of a question and enters a tag that is an alias (`javaee` or `java-ee`), it gets mapped to the canonical form (`j2ee`) for storage.
- In both cases, a note is displayed in the result page (search result, or edit result) giving feedback to the user for the canonical form (e.g. "please note that `j2ee` is preferred on this site over synonym `java-ee`)
- There is a list of aliases that changes in response to user submissions (10K+ users only? voting? not sure).
- The alias list can be viewed on a special page.
- Aliases must be unambiguous (e.g. some 3-letter acronym can't be the alias for 2 canonical forms simultaneously)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was discussed at lenght at one point on UV, but I can't find an existing Meta question.

Comment: As far as I know there hasn't been a question posted about aliases, but it has been brought up as an answer:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/do-23-000-tags-need-tag-database-editors/1529#1529