# Merge svn and subversion tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

Now that a batch-retagging feature has [seemingly been implimented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/batch-retagging/2595#2595) (for moderators), a tag merge request:

[svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) is an abbreviation for [subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subversion) - the two could be merged, probably into the more commonly used `svn`?

This is the case on both StackOverflow and ServerFault

*Edit*: The subversion tag is back.. Used about 33 times on SO..

Comment: Took a while to parse the first sentence. Probably needs s/Not/Now - not enough rep yet to edit it myself.

Comment: @laalto - fixed (I think)

Comment: I'd hold off on doing this until a feature is implemented to "strongly suggest" using 'svn' if someone types 'subversion', otherwise you'll just have to keep doing it. The same would go for 'hg' -> 'mercurial', 'bk' -> bitkeeper, etc.

Comment: "ops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support" erm, okay

Comment: Removed, but it highlights tinkertim's point. =

Comment: Yep            :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Agreed they are duplicates. I propose we leave this here for a day or so simply to gather agreement that svn is the desired master (which is my assumption).

Default: keep svn, remove subversion; any dissenters speak now...

Comment: Personally, i like `subversion` much more than `svn`... but looking at the current usage, `svn` is not only more popular, it fits better with related tags (`svn-merge`, `tortoisesvn` ...) So, ++ - merge away...

Comment: (note I deliberately wiki'd this in case anyone thinks I'm just after rep for clicking a few simple buttons ;-p)

Comment: Your community-wiki'ing wont protect you from the +15 of Accepted-answer'ness :P

Comment: Actually, yes it will. AFAIK, there is no +15 on wiki

Comment: Opps, true, I misread another question which (I thought) implied there was..

Comment: subversion shall perish! Long live svn!

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question than an answer, but surely in time the "subversion" tag will creep back in? Is there a mechanism to suggest "svn" to users that type "subversion" in the tagging box?

Comment: A mechanism has been proposed, but there is no process/system for that just yet.

Comment: I agree, its very likely that people will continue to type subversion, since its the full name of the project. The same would go for hg -> mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Are we going to have new question for each retag proposal?

Comment: Not sure, but this was the first one, before http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg was created :P

Comment: Yes, at least that's what Marc Gravell had in mind, I think http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/should-mass-tag-edits-removal-be-throttled-or-put-to-the-community-for-voting/2775#2775

Comment: I'm happy either way; this one has about 30: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg

Answer (score 0):

The "subversion" tag is back and attempting to reassert its presence.  We need a permanent alias to excise the scourge of its existence once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

Great, so now we have hg going to mercurial, **BUT** subversion going to svn.

I think this is mega confusing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50091#50091 ?