# Can the Batch re-tag feature automatically remove duplicate tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, moderation

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138597/rearranging-project-after-svn-checkout) question that has two `svn` tags, I assume it is because of [this retag request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/batch-retag-request-merge-svn-and-subversion).

So can the batch retag facility check if there will be duplicate tags when it completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a moderator function which deduplicates all current question tags, and all post history tag entries.

So the next time there's a duplicate tag problem, just flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll run the tag deduplicator page.

Comment: Does this mean a merge like http://stackoverflow.com/tags/session%20sessions (pending synonym merge) needs 35 manual de-duplications? I [assumed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62457/tag-merges-lead-to-duplicate-tags-on-locked-questions-closed) they would be automatically de-duplicated...

Answer (score 8):

Or, perhaps simpler - have a daily script to de-dup them.

Comment: That would work for me, since it would clean up a lot that we might not be alerted to.

Comment: I thought this script already existed, was I wrong?