# Questions tagged with the same tag twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I noticed a bunch of those 'r' questions on Stack Overflow have been tagged something like 'r r plot' or 'r ide r'.

Is this a bug?  Either way it seems redundant so I cleaned up a bunch of them.

Comment: +1 for actually being a good citizen and cleaning up some of the posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a residual of retagging `r-language` to `r`, where many questions had both tags. The retagging function doesn't check to see if it will cause duplicate tags.

Comment: Go here for more information
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/can-the-batch-re-tag-feature-automatically-remove-duplicate-tags

Answer (score 2):

For info, the related <kbd>retag-request</kbd> is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/retag-request-sort-out-r-vs-r-language). As has been stated, the bulk re-tagging doesn't currently check for duplicates. It would be nice if it did (and I expect that this will get fixed in time; either as part of retagging, or as a separate de-dup script). But not today.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058783/regular-expression-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-words/1212118#1212118) to clean up the duplicate tags.

We may have to run this periodically depending on how much renaming goes on..

edit: I've added a moderator function which deduplicates all current question tags, and all post history tag entries. The next time there's a duplicate tag problem, just flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll run the tag deduplicator page.