# Is it allowed to have the same tag repeating on the question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I found this Superuser question had the '`software-rec`' tag twice:
[Best/Preferred software for photography](https://superuser.com/questions/41670/best-preferred-software-for-photography) ([revisions](https://superuser.com/revisions/41670/list)).

How was the second instance allowed to be tagged?
I expected the duplicate tag to be automatically cleared/dissolved when `Lance` saved the edit.

Removed the duplicate tag (see the revisions link).
But, is this expected behavior?

If it is allowed to repeat a tag -- why?

---

Update:
If as `random` says, a global conversion caused the duplication of this tag,
I'd still kind-of expect the conversion to be implemented to check for such duplicates
(caused by it).

I would also be surprised to find someone choose to shorten a tag and
did not delete the older longer form (for the conversion to cause a duplicate later).

Comment: Let's invoke Lance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts

Comment: @random +1, nice idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a moderator function which deduplicates all current question tags, and all post history tag entries.

So the next time there's a duplicate tag problem, just flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll run the tag deduplicator page.

Answer (score 4):

**`[software-rec]`** [used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/superuser-tagging-question-software-hardware-product-recommendations) **`[software-recommendation]`** so it's possible that when Lance went to retag, it was already sporting the latter.

And then some global merge/rename (of the latter style to the former) left the question with [the case of duplicate tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/can-the-batch-re-tag-feature-automatically-remove-duplicate-tags).

Comment: Hmm, so maybe Lance saw the longer form, added the shorter form and then the global conversion shortened the longer one to make a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Not really *valid* - but it happens as an unwanted side-effect of retags (see tags on this question).

I'm hopeful Jeff/team will add a de-dup script (if it doesn't already exist). I'll keep an eye on this question and see if it fixes itself...

Basically, from what I understand from Jeff, the tag-merge script is a simple `UPDATE` command that changes the ids only - it doesn't checks for dups because of the performance cost. But I'm thinking a scheduled job (perhaps once a day) should be reasonable...

Comment: Is this automatically cleaned in some way? Or do we have to manually retag everything?

Comment: Thanks, this is what i would expect too.

Comment: @alex: we have to manually retag everything.