# Tag merges lead to duplicate tags on locked questions

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-abilities, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Batch re-tag feature automatically remove duplicate tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/can-the-batch-re-tag-feature-automatically-remove-duplicate-tags)

The favorite programmer cartoon was tagged with `[fun]` and `[humor]`. The `[humor]` tag was [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62334/please-ban-the-offtopic-tag/62342#62342) into `[fun]` and now the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/thats-what-we-show-new-users-as-one-of-the-most-highly-regarded-questions) has that tag twice. [Dirty computer science jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639361/are-there-computer-science-dirty-jokes-closed) also seem to be especially funny, probably also since the merge.

Both questions are locked, so that could be the reason why the duplicate tag wasn't automatically removed.

Comment: A better question: Why the hell was the second question locked instead of being deleted outright?

Comment: Also, for the title you added in the link to the first question I accidentally read it as "retarded" instead of "regarded". Oddly enough, they both make the same amount of sense.