# Can merge tags (from synonyms page) remove duplicates created as a result of merge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

So I merged tags, and it created duplicate tags.   I came to meta to write a bug report and saw this question: [Can the Batch re-tag feature automatically remove duplicate tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/can-the-batch-re-tag-feature-automatically-remove-duplicate-tags)

That sounds like what I want, but the answer didn't really address the question.   Why should I go merge and then have to go do a second step of removing duplicates?   If I'm merging [tag-a](/questions/tagged/tag-a) and [tag-b](/questions/tagged/tag-b) and a question is tagged with both [tag-a](/questions/tagged/tag-a) and [tag-b](/questions/tagged/tag-b), I want it to end up with [tag-a](/questions/tagged/tag-a) only and not [tag-a](/questions/tagged/tag-a) [tag-a](/questions/tagged/tag-a).

I think the system even knows this is going to happen based on what was displayed on the confirm-merge page.

Comment: How does Jeff's answer not address the problem? It sounds like there's another page that has the deduplicating functionality.

Comment: @JonSeigel I'm asking that it happens automatically.   Merging tags is likely to create duplicates.  Why do I have to go to another page to de-duplicate?  Why not have it happen automatically?

Comment: @Jon Unless it's cleverly hidden, diamonds don't have access to such a utility anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue a while back, should be fine now.