# Please merge the "winapi" and "win32" tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Stats:

```
winapi        474
win32        1439

winapi+win32  164
```

I don't know much about Windows programming myself, but [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32), *Win32* and *WinAPI* refer to the same thing.

If these are merged, should we go with the more current `winapi` or the more popular `win32`? Or perhaps something closer to the official name: `windows-api` (currently not used)?

And of course, if you know of a reason why these should *not* be merged, speak up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done... lets hope we're right ;-p

```
updating post history, 2200 rows affected
updating posts, 1554 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [winapi] and [win32] complete!
```

Answer (score 6):

If merged, WinAPI is the one to go as it ranges from Win16 to Win64, as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) shows:

> The Windows API, informally WinAPI, is
>   Microsoft's core set of application
>   programming interfaces (APIs)
>   available in the Microsoft Windows
>   operating systems. It was formerly
>   called the Win32 API; however, the
>   name Windows API more accurately
>   reflects its roots in 16-bit Windows
>   and its support on 64-bit Windows.

I would recommend to use the 64bit and 32bit tags in addition to distinguish where necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I think they should be merged. As far as I'm concerned they're synonyms, and it's better to have everything under one tag.

Edit:
I think winapi should win because wikipedia indicates that "Windows API" is the currently accepted name.

Comment: Which tag you think should be the remaining one?

Answer (score 3):

As Kevin and Ralph note, WinAPI is correct. If folks actually used win32 and win64 to differentiate between questions specific to those variations, then i'd say leave it... but they don't - too many years of hearing Win32 used as the name for the Windows API has made it habit.

Merge to `winapi`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merging fixes things. New questions will come with new tags. So as long as there are people who think of WinAPI as Win32, there will be questions tagged as such. Apart from that, I don't think you have to ask in order to retag everything you see.

Comment: Sure, but the same issue concerns all mass retags. Afaik, there isn't a "permanent" solution for this yet, and the current thinking is to simply have a moderator re-run the operation when it starts to look too bad again.

Comment: Ah, and regarding "I don't think you have to ask in order to retag everything you see"; I'm not asking for permission to do manual retagging. Instead, this is a request for a moderator to do a batch retag. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/batch-retagging/2595#2595

Comment: It might also help that they'll type "win" and see "winapi" suggested with 1900+ next to it and "win32" with a single-digit number.