# Retag request: winapi -> windows-api

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

`[winapi]` has a few tag-synonyms like `[windows-api]` and `[win32-api]`, but the tag is shown as `[winapi]` since it was the most used tag.

But I think that **`[windows-api]`** is a better name. So how about that a mod could retag it to `[windows-api]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bloody HELL! This is why indiscriminately deleting retag requests is a bad idea:

[Tag merge request: [windows-api] and others into [winapi] on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39015/tag-merge-request-windows-api-and-others-into-winapi-on-so) Feb 11
[Retag Request [win32] -> [winapi]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47118/retag-request-win32-winapi) April 18
[Please merge the “winapi” and “win32” tags on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13078/please-merge-the-winapi-and-win32-tags-on-stack-overflow) August 7 2009

Past practice has been to merge toward WinAPI. That's the common name, at least when folks aren't calling it Win32 (which is admittedly more common, but increasingly inaccurate).

Comment: Ah, that explains why I didn't found anything about this when searching. However, for me the name [windows-api] sounds more official than [winapi], i.e. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff404219.aspx

Comment: Wikipedia is also using "Windows API" instead of "Win API". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API

Comment: @Jonas: I know. However, very few SO users use it. Indeed, the majority haven't even used WinAPI - Win32 would be the winner if we didn't keep retagging them. The synonym feature might allow something like this, but I'm not really wild about moving from a reasonably popular tag to an extremely obscure one - chances are, *no one* has "windows-api" in their feeds, searches, or favorites. The other problem I'd have with "windows-api" already exists with winapi, but I fear it would become worse: folks see it as a generic term for "an API used with Windows" and tag all sorts of crap with it.