# Are HTML authoring questions acceptable on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is question 2528290, ["Should we include period “.” in link text?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528290/should-we-include-period-in-link-text), acceptable on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a great question for the mythological "webmaster" trilogy site.

It is absolutely not programming related in my opinion -- markup does not equal "code" -- but I'd rather others voted on it since my vote is binding.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote :P

Comment: A good example supporting this feature-request (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/allow-admins-mods-to-vote-to-close-delete-a-question/389#389) stating that the moderator "super-vote" should be a separate function... allowing moderators to participate in the one-man-one-vote aspect of the site. Even when moderators *know* with every fiber of their being that a post *should* be closed, sometimes it just looks better coming from the community democracy.